# Disable use of the messagebox.show() in a c# application

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been trying to find over the internet if it was possible to disable the use of the `messagebox.show()` function, but so far I haven't found anything useful.

The reason I want to do this is quite simple, in my opinion; I'm starting a new project, where other people will be doing code over the next few years. I've created a new class to handle all of the messages shown to the user, which does a little more than just sending a message to the user. But I want to make sure that this will be the class used, when a programmer other than me works on the project.

So is there a way to show an error in the visual studio's error list to the programmer? Or any other way to make sure that my message class will be used?

Comment: Wouldn't well written comments and a complete documentation of the project prevent these kind of problems?

Comment: @JMichelB: Not sure about you, but I tend to read the documentation only when I've hit a snag... ;)  For implementation of something new I tend to only look at the examples.

Comment: Well it'll help for sure, but won't prevent it from happenning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option I'm aware of is to use a custom code analysis rule:
http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/

Comment: That will probably do the trick, I'll play around with it and get back to you once I get it to work. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If the code analysis rule suggested by Chris isn't enough for you, consider using an **AOP (aspect oriented programming)** toolkit, such as [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp). It allows you to intercept and replace all calls made to Messagebox.Show() with your own code (presumably redirecting it to your implementation).

Note that it might be too heavy-handed for your purposes.

Comment: Doesn't it needs to be run by someone to work? If someone compiles before running PostSharp, then it doesn't change the problem.

Comment: PostSharp can be configured as a post-build step that modifies the assembly. So if the project is configured correctly, every build will produce a modified assembly.

Comment: Interesting solution.  I haven't seen postsharp yet. (+1)